# Падший и павший

Tags: этимология

Употребимы ли в русском языке слова седший (севший) и крадший (кравший) по аналогии с падший и павший?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что пишет "Русская грамматика" в разделе "Причастия прошедшего времени" ([§ 1584](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1759)):

Только от основы прош. вр. образуют действит. причастия прош. вр. глаголы кл. VII с инфинитивом на *-сть: красть, класть, пасть, сесть: кравший* (**не крадший**), *клавший* (**не кладший**), *павший* (**падший** – только прилагательное), *севший.*

Слова "крадший" и "седший" в русском языке не употребляются.